# SQL Server trigger on insert and how to reference the data that was inserted

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert

High level I have two tables that need to have some of the data mirrored. I can't go through and change all of the code to write to both so I thought I'd use a SQL trigger to insert data into the 2nd table anytime data is inserted into the 1st. Here is where I am stuck:

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_trigger_INSERT
ON old_table
FOR INSERT
INSERT INTO new_table (id, first_name, last_name)
VALUES () --This is where I'm lost, I need to insert some of the data from the insert that executed this trigger
```

Any help is appreciated, also if there is a better way to accomplish this let me know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the '*inserted*' table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_trigger_INSERT 
ON old_table 
FOR INSERT 
INSERT INTO new_table (id, first_name, last_name) 
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM inserted
```

[PS: Don't forget to ensure your triggers handle multiple rows...]

Ref. [Create Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Good article: [Exploring SQL Server Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx)

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize those tables existed. What do you mean by ensuring the trigger handles multiple rows?

Comment: @jon3laze: a common mistake made by a lot of "trigger newbies" is to assume the trigger will be fired once for each row inserted - hence they assume the "Inserted" table will only contain a single row. This is not the way it works - if you insert a batch of 50 rows, your INSERT trigger will be fired **once** for the whole batch, and the "Inserted" table will contain 50 rows - you need to be able to deal with that scenario

Answer (score 1):

In the triggers you have "inserted" and "deleted" tables. In this case you only use the "inserted" table, but in update trigger you use both.

Comment: Could you please elaborate some more?