# How to refer to the new inserted row in TSQL Trigger

Tags: t-sql

I know that in plpgsql if one would want to refer to the new inserted row, you can use "`NEW`".
How can I do this in T-SQL (transact sql)?

The following is the trigger I am trying to create:

```
CREATE Trigger setAlertId on rules_table
FOR INSERT AS
DECLARE @max_id integer
SELECT @max_id = (select max(AlertId) from rules_table)
NEW.AlertId = @max_id+1
END
GO
```

I get the error message:

> Incorrect syntax near 'NEW'

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server trigger on insert and how to reference the data that was inserted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404219/sql-server-trigger-on-insert-and-how-to-reference-the-data-that-was-inserted)

Answer (score 0):

[`inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx):

> DML trigger statements use two special tables: the `deleted` table and the `inserted` tables. SQL Server automatically creates and manages these tables. You can use these temporary, memory-resident tables to test the effects of certain data modifications and to set conditions for DML trigger actions. You cannot directly modify the data in the tables

Answer (score 0):

In your case why dont you use an identity on the alertid field that increments itself?
If you want to do it in your trigger you will need to select your primary key from inserted and then do an update on rules tables.